# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, mime-types

I was going through my Gemfile updating to the latest releases when I got this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.2) ruby depends on
      mime-types (~> 1.16) ruby

    mechanize (= 2.7.3) ruby depends on
      mime-types (2.0)
```

Is it true that Rails 4.0.2 is depending on a much older version of mime-types than a lot of gems that are out there or is there something wrong with my local configuration?

P.S. I tried updating the dependencies with ´bundle update´, but I just got the same error again.

Comment: Hm. 1.16 is available on rubygems.org, but as far as I understand the `~>` operator it should match v1.25.1. BRB, digging some more :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem mime-types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25049694/bundler-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-gem-mime-types)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rails` requires `mime-types` with a version of `1.16` or greater, but smaller than `2.0`. However, `mechanize` requires `mime-types` with a version of `2.0` or greater.

I suggest you drop the `mechanize`-version to `2.7.2`:

```
gem 'mechanize', '2.7.2'
```

This will resolve your conflict.

Comment: Although that wasn't the original question it's good to know that it isn't a problem with my local configuration.

Comment: Oh, sorry, for your original question: Yes :)