# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem mime-types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, mime-types, strip

Super baffled by this problem.  Everything is working great local but when I deploy to Heroku it hits this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 3.2.17) ruby depends on
mime-types (~> 1.16) ruby
stripe (>= 0) ruby depends on
mime-types (2.3)
```

I've tried gem installing mime-types 2.3 both in the gemfile and from the command line and neither have given any great results, though maybe it's from my lack of experience.

If I had hair I'd be pulling it out!  Again, this problem only happens when deploying to Heroku.  Everything bundle installs and updates fine locally.

Comment: What version is mime-types in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with how Gemfile.lock works but it's listed 5 times (I'm guessing as a dependency for other gems) with versions varying from `mime-types (>= 1.25, < 3.0)` to `mime-types (~> 1.16)` to `mime-types (1.25.1)`.  2.3 is NOT listed.  I did try to remove these when doing `gem mime-types ~> 2.3` but it didn't work as expected...or at all.

Comment: Yeah, you shouldn't ever have to edit Gemfile.lock. Did you get this error while running `bundle install` on Heroku? It looks like Bundler is resolving dependencies incorrectly. Stripe requires `'mime-types', '>= 1.25', '< 3.0'` so 1.25.1 should satisfy it if I understand it correctly. What if you do `heroku run bundle install`?

Comment: @kitkat `heroku run bundle install` runs successfully but deploying still gives the same error.  The error only comes when deploying.

Comment: Okay, what version of mime-types did `heroku run bundle install` output? Something like 'Using mine-types (x.y.z)'. I want to see if bundler resolves correctly when run on its own.

Comment: @kitkat It says `using mime-types (1.25.1)`

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas. I'd verify that the error happens during `bundle install` (check the logs), then take it up with Heroku support and note that bundler behaves differently by itself vs in the deployment script.

Comment: @kitkat I appreciate your time and suggestions!  I just tried running `heroku run bundle update` and the error happens just as if I did `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve a similar problem:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.7) ruby depends on
      mime-types (~> 1.16) ruby

    stripe (~> 1.15.0) ruby depends on
      mime-types (2.3)
```

By throwing away my `Gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm.. that will update every single one of your gems that you haven't specified a version for. Not exactly a great idea unless you have 100% test coverage.

Comment: I always specify the versions of each gem so that I can do stuff like this if I need to.  And 100% test coverage rocks!

Comment: @user3670743 i am getting error while running rake task through whenever   only

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to resolve this msg,

go to your `gemfile.lock` and change your mime-types version to **`1.25.1`**,

rub bundle install again, then go back to `Gemfile.lock` and switch `mime-types` to `2.4.3`, and again run bundle install :)

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update mime-types` resolved my problem